# How do I show columns where there are only two words in sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

For example I have a tabled named car with two columns(col1,col2) and also I'm gonna inserted some values inside the columns:

('Black super car','Black supper')

('Yellow   car','Yellow car')

('Green','Green car')

So for now I want to display only ('Yellow car','Yellow car') by using regexp_like statement (regular expression), how do I do that? I would appreciate any suggestions

I tried this and it never gonna work:

```
select * from car where regexp_like(col1,'[ ]*')
```

Comment: When asking these type of questions it could help if you also provide the database you are using.

Comment: @Ruud Verhoef   Oh I'm sorry, I'm using sql developer. Thanks for your quick reply sir.

Comment: You can learn regex if you [read this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/B14251_01/adfns_regexp.htm). Good luck!

Comment: @AntonioVenerosoContreras   Oh my gosh it's worked! thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `col1` as input string and `col2` as pattern in `regexp_like` as following:

```
Select * from your_table
Where regexp_like(col1,col2)
```

See this [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f44591ad6df2bc09046cd363c1f93471).

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

> How do I show columns where there are only two words in sql

You can use `like` if you define word as separated by one space:

```
where col1 like '% %' and
      col1 not like '% % %'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir, can we do it by using regexp_like statement?

Comment: @TIGUZI . . . This answers the question in your title, which is apparently not the question you really wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from car where col1 = col2
```